# Passing parse objects through cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

Can you pass parse objects from iOS into Cloud Code and vice versa, or would you have to pass the objectID and query through the objects?

Comment: You pass by using the object id anyway, so it could be a raw I'd or it could be wrapped in an object, in either case you can create an object easily in cloud code to use. Show a specific example where you have an issue.